# Form for an object that has a join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, join

Suppose I have three tables:

---

**company**

- id
- name

---

**cars**

- id
- name

---

**companies_cars**

- company_id
- car_id

---

Knowing that a person can have many cars, and that there are already many cars registered in the database, how can I make a form to register a **new** user and check which cars he has?

This form will have an input field for the name and one check box for each registered car.

I have tried to do it in many ways and looked for an answer in the web, but nothing that I tried worked :/.

Comment: Checkout this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2qwV0B9yfU

Comment: That is such an awesome material :o

Answer (score 1):

You can give him select-list with multiple selection:

```
= form_for @user,
           url: user_path,
           html: { class: 'form-class', method: :post } do |f|
  = f.text_field :name,
                 class: 'name-class'
  = f.select :cars_ids,
             options_from_collection_for_select(Car.all, :id, :name),
             {},
             { multiple: true,
               class: 'cars-class', 
               data: { placeholder: 'Select one ore more...' } }
  = f.submit 'Register',
             class: 'button-class'
```

Then in params (after submission), you will receive an array of ids of selected cars.
I suppose you also should permit `cars_ids` key in params (I'm not using classic rails-way, so can not check).
And don't forget to create `users` table, appropriate model etc.

Comment: Hello, @tbard! What are you using? Thanks!

Comment: For form objects, I'm using Reform gem.